# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Tags: php

Ola, segue o erro se puderem me dar um auxilio !

```
   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 

       $limite = 5;
       $page_atual = !preg_replace('/[^0-9]+',',$_GET['var1']');
```

erro:

```
     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_GET' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/sisv2/sis_adm/version/abcvp/includes/cursoseventos.inc.php on line 121
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem uma `'` a mais no meio e no fim. Qual das opções você deseja?

```
$page_atual = !preg_replace('/[^0-9]+\',',$_GET['var1']);
```

Ou (faz mais sentido):

```
$page_atual = !preg_replace('/[^0-9]+',$_GET['var1']);
```